# what is innerHtml alternative in riotjs

Tags: innerhtml, riot.js

**What is the alternative of innerHTML in RiotJs**

For example when we have

```html
<h1 id="one">asdfghjkl</h1>
```

in JavaScript we can use

```js
var str = document.getElementById("one").innerHTML;
```

but for the same HTML tag how do we get that value in RiotJs?

I know `riot.id` will return value `"one"`
what function will return value "asdfghjkl" instead of `</yield>`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you would like to get the innerHTML of your created tag. That is as easy as "this.root.innerHTML".

```
<riot-tag>
   asdfghjkl
   <script>
      this.on('updated', function(){
         console.log(this.getInnerHTML());
      });
      getInnerHTML(){
         return this.root.innerHTML;
      }
   </script>
</riot-tag>
```

If you need the innerHTML of any sub-element of your created tag set a name or id property on the element and reference it directly. Or if you are calling your function from an event, like click, have the element reference from e.target.

```
<riot-tag>
   <h1 onclick={getInnerHTML} name="myTagHeader">asdfghjkl</h1>
   <script>
      getInnerHTML(e){
         console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
         console.log(this.myTagHeader.innerHTML);
      }
   </script>
</riot-tag>
```

Hope that it will help

Comment: Sorry Both of these solutions are not applicable. Riot uses the class "opts" and i need that perticuler function of this class that is used to access the inner text of any tag.

Comment: Would you like a property on opts to hold the innerhtml of your element?